# OpenMP only using one thread

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp

I have having a bit of a frustrating problem with openmp.  When I run the following code it only seems to be running on one thread.

```
    omp_set_num_threads(8);    
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) //jobs is a vector
    {
        std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << "\t" << omp_get_num_threads() << "\t" << omp_in_parallel() << std::endl;
        jobs[i].run();
    }
```

This prints...

> 0 1 1

for every line.

I can see using top that openmp is spawning as many threads as I have the process taskset to.  They are mostly idle while it runs.  The program is both compiled and linked with the -fopenmp flag with gcc.  I am using redhat 6.  I also tried using the `num_threads(8)` parameter in the pragma which made no difference.  The program is linked with another library which also uses openmp so maybe this is the issue.  Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?  In all my past openmp experience it has just worked.

Comment: there's no load in `run()`?

Comment: What exactly does `run()` do? Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Each call of run could be doing something completely different.  Each call of run can take about 0.5s.  And there are usually more than 20 jobs.  I can not really reproduce this outside of this one large coding project.

Comment: _"Each call of run could be doing something completely different."_ I think OpenMP tasks would be the better way to go then anyway...

Comment: Does `run()` do anything in parallel?

Comment: I don't think so but it might be worth checking.

Comment: Well if it does, then that might explain why your loop only runs on 1 thread. You'd have to enable nesting and control the number of threads for each level separately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print your jobs.size()?

I made a quick test and it does work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2);

#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) //jobs is a vector
    {
#pragma omp ordered
        std::cout << i << "\t" << omp_get_thread_num() << "\t" << omp_get_num_threads() << "\t" << omp_in_parallel() << std::endl;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

I got:

icpc -qopenmp test.cpp && ./a.out

```
0 0 2 1
1 1 2 1
2 0 2 1
3 1 2 1
```

Comment: I did about the same test in a standalone program and it also worked.  I don't have the code with me right now but I can tell you jobs.size() > 20 and each job takes about 0.5 seconds to run.

Comment: Ok. In this case, in your original code, try to reduce as much as possible the problem. Comment out  jobs[i].run(); and check again.